# How to change src from input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the src value from an input using javascript?

```
<input class="url" id="url1" type="url" value="youtube url">
<input onclick="changevideo()" class="add-video" id="add-video1" type="submit" value="add to playlist">

<iframe class="video" id="video1" ></iframe>

<script>
    function changevideo() {
        var ddd = document.getElementById('url').value;
        document.getElementById('video1').setAttribute('src', ddd);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: uncomment your `var ddd` declaration and fix your syntax: `document.getElementById('video1').setAttribute('src', ddd);`

Comment: Also change the ```document.getElementById('url')``` to ```document.getElementById('url1')```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help! I tried to change it but it still won't work for me.

Comment: Does it returns any error?

Comment: Yes, this is the error message that comes in the console: SCRIPT1006: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
player.html (79,66)

14SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'changevideo' is not defined

Comment: Try this

                function changevideo() {
                    var ddd = document.getElementById('url1').value;
                    document.getElementById('video1').setAttribute('src', ddd);
                }

Comment: I got it to work. document.getElementById('video1').setAttribute('src', ddd);

Comment: Yeah. It is because your missing ')' on the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

```js
function changevideo() {
var e=document.querySelector('#url1').value;
console.log(e)
  document.getElementById('video1').setAttribute('src', e)
  }
```

```html
<input class="url" id="url1" type="url" value="youtube url">
<input onclick="changevideo()" class="add-video" id="add-video1" type="submit" value="add to playlist">
<iframe class="video" id="video1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have access to the `src` attribute when selecting the video:
    `let video = document.getElementById('video1');
     video.src = path;`